# Why my window.location.href doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, onclick

My codes are like this.

```
function deleteAction(obj,tableName){
    inputs=obj.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input");
    newValues="";

    for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
        newValues+=inputs[i].value+",";
    }

    url="http://localhost:8081/SimpleWeb/SimpleServlet?action=delete&tableName="+tableName+"&newValue="+newValues;
    window.location.href=url;
}
```

I have made sure that that function will be run when I click on the button with Chrome's debug.

And the string url is valid because I can copy it to the browser and open the page correctly.

But in this function the `window.location.href` just doesn't work even if I change the url into "http://google.com"...Why

Comment: perhaps you need to use `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: Are you sure your deleteAction function is being run? You can put an alert in it to check for instance.

Comment: Please test it if you reach that line: put an `alert('before redirect line')` to try.

Comment: "click on the button", please show how you have attached the click event, and where all the variables (those which are not defined in the post) are defined. Notice also, that the default action of a button within a form is to submit the form, which blocks changes to `location.href`.

Comment: @Bellash    I am very sure the function is being run because I added a breakpoint into the function with Chrome.

Comment: And I can copy the url and open it in browser maybe I don't need to encode it ? @Daniel A. White

Comment: I am very sure the function is being run because I added a breakpoint into the function with Chrome. @Steven Lemmens

Comment: <button onclick="updateAction(this,'student')">update</button> My codes are like this. @Teemu

Comment: And the `button` is within a `form`?

Comment: @Teemu Yes, does it matter?

Comment: Like I said in my comment above, when a browser is ready to submit a form, changes to `location.href` is blocked. Set `type="button"` for the button to prevent submission.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks! I realize that I don't need form tag at all so I delete it and   the page can jump correctly now. Can you post an answer then I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

is `i` variable global? After looking well, I suggest you change from this

```
 for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    newValues+=inputs[i].value+",";
 }
```

to

```
for(var j=0;j<inputs.length;j++){
    newValues+=inputs[j].value+",";
}
```